# How to remove all html tags from django template?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I would like to use django template for e-mail sending.
But I should have two version of e-mails - html and plain text. The first version is generated like below:

```
template_values = {
     'company_id': company.id
     }
template_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/email.html')
html = template.render(template_file, template_values)
```

Now I should generate plain text from the same file - `templates/email.html`, but it contains html tags (like `<div style="font-size:13px; margin: 14px; position:relative">`), which I should remove (links should stay, but should be replaced with plain text, for ex., `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>` should be replaced with something like `Example (http://example.com)`).

I've read that I shouldn't use regex for this. What kind of built-in GAE library can help me? Or is there any way to use somehow django's [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags)?

Comment: A common way to achieve this is to use another template for the other email format 'text'.

Comment: [django-templated-email](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email)

Comment: @jpic, thanks. If I use separate plain text django template, looks like end of line characters are removed. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you get the HTML, you need to do something like:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

template_values = {
     'company_id': company.id
}
template_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/email.html')
html = template.render(template_file, template_values)

plain_text = strip_tags(html)
```